# VueJS access child component's data from parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I'm using the [vue-cli scaffold for webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)

My Vue component structure/heirarchy currently looks like the following:

- App

  - PDF Template

    - Background
    - Dynamic Template Image
    - Static Template Image
    - Markdown

At the app level, I want a vuejs component method that can aggregate all of the child component's data into a single JSON object that can be sent off to the server.

**Is there a way to access child component's data? Specifically, multiple layers deep?**

If not, what is the best practice for passing down oberservable data/parameters, so that when it's modified by child components I have access to the new values? I'm trying to avoid hard dependencies between components, so as of right now, the only thing passed using component attributes are initialization values.

**UPDATE:**

Solid answers. Resources I found helpful after reviewing both answers:

- [Vuex and when to use it](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)
- [Vuex alternative solution for smaller apps](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For this kind of structure It's good to have some kind of Store.

VueJS provide solution for that, and It's called Vuex.If you are not ready to go with Vuex, you can create your own simple store.

Let's try with this

*MarkdownStore.js*

```
export default {

 data: {
   items: []
 },

 // Methods that you need, for e.g fetching data from server etc.

 fetchData() {
   // fetch logic
 }

}
```

And now you can use those data everywhere, with importing this Store file

*HomeView.vue*

```
import MarkdownStore from '../stores/MarkdownStore'

export default {

 data() {
   sharedItems: MarkdownStore.data
 },

 created() {
   MarkdownStore.fetchData()
 }

}
```

So that's the basic flow that you could use, If you dont' want to go with Vuex.

Comment: [Documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) explains it pretty good as well.

Comment: What if I want to move fetchData() logic inside MarkdownStore. it makes sense to put all the components logic inside the component.

Comment: This solution almost worked for me.  I can access the fetchData() method, but that method can not access the data in the MarkdownStore view.  this.data.items, or this.$data.items didn't work

Comment: @YeeHaw1234 you should access It by `this.items`, from your component.

Comment: @Toast I truly believe the documentation could (must) say more about the matter.

Answer (score 95):

In certain scenarios, the parent can directly access their child's data using its reference

e.g

```
<markdown ref="markdowndetails"></markdown>
<app-button @submit="process"></app-button>

// js
methods:{
    process: function(){
        // items is a defined object inside data()
        var markdowns = this.$refs.markdowndetails.items 
    }
}
```

for complex state management scenarios, an effective approach would be to use Vuex.

Comment: Where can i find the documentation for this?

Comment: @Jujubes https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

Comment: Worked well for me - Thanks @PJ3

Comment: It's simple method to pass data from child to parent, the emit is more complicated. Thanks

Comment: @BesLey I think they have different use cases. If the component is designed to be a child of another specific component, then accessing its internal data directly maybe the right choice, like getters/setters in object oriented programming. But if the component is to used in different places then event method is the more appropriate one.

Answer (score 35):

> what is the best practice for passing down oberservable data/parameters, so that when it's modified by child components I have access to the new values?

The flow of props is one way down, a child should never modify its props directly.

For a complex application, vuex is the solution, but for a simple case vuex is an overkill. Just like what @Belmin said, you can even use a plain JavaScript object for that, thanks to the reactivity system.

Another solution is using events. Vue has already implemented the EventEmitter interface, a child can use `this.$emit('eventName', data)` to communicate with its parent.

The parent will listen on the event like this: (`@update` is the shorthand of `v-on:update`)

```
<child :value="value" @update="onChildUpdate" />
```

and update the data in the event handler:

```
methods: {
  onChildUpdate (newValue) {
    this.value = newValue
  }
}
```

Here is a simple example of custom events in Vue:
http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/ZBELjm?editors=1010

This is just parent-child communication, if a component needs to talk to its siblings, then you will need a global event bus, in Vue.js, you can just use an empty Vue instance:

```
const bus = new Vue()

// In component A
bus.$on('somethingUpdated', data => { ... })

// In component B
bus.$emit('somethingUpdated', newData)
```

Answer (score 17):

you can meke ref to child component and use it as this
this.$refs.refComponentName.$data

parent-component

```
<template>
   <section>
      <childComponent ref="nameOfRef" />
   </section>
</template>

 methods: {
  save() {
   let Data = this.$refs.nameOfRef.$data;
 }
},
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I have a registration form that I've broken down into components.

As suggested above I used $refs, In my parent I have for example:

In Template:

```
<Personal ref="personal" />
```

Script - Parent Component

```
export default {
  components: {
    Personal,
    Employment
  },
  data() {
    return {
        personal: null,
        education: null
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
       this.personal = this.$refs.personal.model
       this.education = this.$refs.education.model
  }
}
```

This works well as the data is reactive.

Comment: with this type of solution I am getting type errors does anyone have a typescript solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody's mentioned the use of Provide/Inject.  I'm not saying this is the best way, but it is "a" way of creating a simple grand-parent/grand-child reactivity without having to worry about the complexities of data-stores.

As usual, the following solution comes with a health warning.  Only use it on small-scale simplified apps where you know the grand-child will always be a descendant of the grandfather!  Blah, blah....

(By the way, this works in Vue3 with Composition API.)

```
// Grandparent component
<script setup>
import { ref, provide } from 'vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'

const message = ref('hello')

function changeMessage(e) {
    message.value = e.target.value;
}

provide('message', { message, changeMessage});
</script>

<template>
    <p>The value from the grandchild is: {{ message }}</p>
    <Child />
</template>
```

In my simple example, the Child component does nothing but to prove that the reactivity logic can pass it by:

```
// file: Child.vue
<script setup>
import GrandChild from './GrandChild.vue'
</script>
<template>
    <GrandChild />
</template>
```

And the Grand-child looks like this:

```
// file: GrandChild.vue
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'
const { message, changeMessage } = inject('message');
</script>

<template>
    <p>
        Message to send grandparent: <input :value="message" @input="changeMessage" />
    </p>
</template>
```

When you type your message in the `<input />` box on the grand-child, the grand-parent will reflect that message.

Documentation:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html