# How do I use data from Vue.js child component within parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a form component where I use a child component. I want to use data from the child component within the parent.

My component in html:

```
<candidates-form endpoint='/candidates/create' buttontext='Add Candidate'></candidates-form>
```

Then here is the Vue instance:

**CandidatesForm.vue**

```
<template>
<div class='row'>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' v-model='name'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <location-input></location-input>
    </div>

    <button class='btn btn-primary'>{{buttontext}}</button>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {}
        },

        props: ['endpoint', 'buttontext'],

        ready() {}
    }
</script>
```

I utilize the locationInput component in there and it renders to the screen nicely. That component implements Google Maps typeahead functionality for the input field and looks like this:

**LocationInput.vue**

```
<template>

    <place-input
            :place.sync="placeInput.place"
            :types.sync="placeInput.types"
            :component-restrictions.sync="placeInput.restrictions"
            class='form-control'
            label='Location: '
            name='location'
    ></place-input>

    <pre>{{ placeInput.place | json }}</pre>

</template>

<script>
    import { PlaceInput, Map } from 'vue-google-maps'

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                placeInput: {
                    place: {
                        name: ''
                    },
                    types: [],
                    restrictions: {'country': 'usa'}
                }
            }
        },
        props: ['location'],

        components: {
            PlaceInput
        },
        ready() {
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
    label { display: block; }
</style>
```

I want to submit the `name` value and information from `placeInput.place` to the server.

I register both components in my main app file like so:

```
Vue.component('locationInput', require('./components/LocationInput.vue'));
Vue.component('candidatesForm', require('./components/CandidatesForm.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});
```

How do I pass the `placeInput.place` data from location-input component to candidates-form component?

I want to send the placeInput.place and name data from the candidates-form component to the server, most likely using vue-resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey no need for a store or Vuex. Pass data using props!

**Final solution:**

Blade template:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
        <h1>Add New Candidate</h1>
        <hr>
        <candidates-form endpoint='/candidates/create' buttontext='Add Candidate'></candidates-form>
    </div>
@stop
```

Parent Vue component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' v-model='name'>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <location-input :location="locationData"></location-input>
    </div>

    <button class='btn btn-primary'>{{buttontext}}</button>

    <pre>{{ locationData | json }}</pre>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            locationData: {
                place: {
                    name: ''
                },
                types: [],
                restrictions: {'country': 'usa'}
            }
        }
    },
    props: ['endpoint', 'buttontext']
}
</script>
```

Child Vue component:

```
<template>
    <place-input
            :place.sync="location.place"
            :types.sync="location.types"
            :component-restrictions.sync="location.restrictions"
            class='form-control'
            label='Location: '
            name='location'
    ></place-input>
</template>

<script>
    import { PlaceInput, Map } from 'vue-google-maps'

    export default {
        props: ['location'],
        components: {
            PlaceInput
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
    label { display: block; }
</style>
```

Aaaaand the overall app.js file (this is within a Laravel 5.3 app btw)

```
import { load } from 'vue-google-maps'

load({
  key: '<API_KEY>',
  v: '3.24',             // Google Maps API version
  libraries: 'places',   // for places input
});

Vue.component('locationInput', require('./components/LocationInput.vue'));
Vue.component('candidatesForm', require('./components/CandidatesForm.vue'));
Vue.component('company-list', require('./components/CompanyList.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});
```

[This article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/intro-to-component-props/) from alligator.io also helped simplify things for me also. I was overthinking it!

Shout out to @GuillaumeLeclerc for the vue-google-maps component: https://github.com/GuillaumeLeclerc/vue-google-maps

Comment: I find adding v-model support to the custom component is a much better solution. You will find here a very helpful article:
https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the data store approach which is in the VueJS documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Essentially you would have a `store.js` file that exports a data object for your application. This data object is shared with all of your components.

From the page linked above:

```
const sourceOfTruth = {}
const vmA = new Vue({
  data: sourceOfTruth
})
const vmB = new Vue({
  data: sourceOfTruth
})
```

and if you need components to have private state along with shared state:

```
var vmA = new Vue({
  data: {
    privateState: {},
    sharedState: store.state
  }
})
var vmB = new Vue({
  data: {
    privateState: {},
    sharedState: store.state
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks. Looks like I need to implement a store for this to work

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here [VueJS access child component's data from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410332/vuejs-access-child-components-data-from-parent/40411389#40411389) , pretty same questions.

If you are working with large scale application, the best option is to use Vuex, it would save you from a lot of troubles.

Otherwise if it's not a bug app, then you can go with my approach, or using Event Bus.