# How to best tackle sharing of state between components in same view

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a projects view that contains 3 components, `<project-item>`, `<project-list>` and `<project-view>`. All of these components need to be aware of the selected projects.

- `<project-item>` holds the state for a particular project. This component has a property called selected which determines if the project is selected or not.
- `<project-list>` houses one or more project-items and has a computed property which checks the children are of type `<project-item>` and which items are selected.
- `<project-view>` is the general view which just contains navigation and logic associated UAC.

The hierarchy looks like this...

```
<project-view>
    <project-list>
        <project-item selected></project-item>
    </project-list>
</project-view>
```

What would be the best way of sharing that state as i feel **vuex** is the wrong choice here as it's not global state.

I also have tried to use a computed property on the `<project-view>` component to get the selected items on the `<project-list>` component but it throws errors despite existing and being in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuex is your answer.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

This is the solution for the sharing of states.

You will create the store, connect your states with store and use actions/mutations to work with them.

It will give you great foundation for state sharing which, if you will need to, you will easily scale up.

Good luck!

Comment: I always have seen Vuex as a global state not one between a couple of components which is why i don't think it's right to use this method.

Comment: It is right. Always when developing stuff, use scalable solutions. You never know how your project will grow up. Introduction time of Vuex is like 20-30 minutes, it is not big job.

Comment: I already use it but only on stuff i consider the entire application needs to be aware of but it's a fair point, i can't see why i can't use it on a smaller scale too.

Answer (score 2):

If you think that Vuex is overkill, then check my answer here - pretty same topic

[VueJS access child component's data from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410332/vuejs-access-child-components-data-from-parent/40411389#40411389)