# Vue.js where to store non-component data properties?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I am working on a project with Vue.js and I use components most of the time, but sometimes I would just like to add some Vue.js syntax without completely creating a component.

Because I do not use the render like you normally would the entire HTML content that Vue attaches to is not being overwritten, allowing me to `sprinkle` some Vue.js syntax on existing HTML.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    name: 'Vue root',
    data: {
      store
    },
    components: {
        Example
    }
});
```

An example of adding some Vue.js syntax to existing HTML would be; keeping 2 inputs in sync with each other for example:

**Form one on index.html**

```
<input type="text" attributes... v-model="store.arrival">
```

**Form two on index.html**

```
<input type="text" attributes... v-model="store.arrival">
```

Before I introduced the store I got a message saying something along the lines of:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "arrival" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
>   (found in root instance)

This led me to introducing this store because I do not want to bloat the data property of my root component in that file by rather keep an overview of these `floating in space(because they do not belong to a component)` properties.

I love the ability to still add Vue syntax to existing HTML but this feels like bad practice.

Is there a better way to store these variables than in store(which can get crowded pretty fast)? Or should I actually just move everything into components? This also leads to problems because than I am forced to transform things like PHP variables to Javascript if I need them.

Hopefully it is clear what I mean, thanks for reading and I you need more info let me know.

Cheers.

Comment: I am not very clear with your expectations but I think mixins will help you. Have you looked into it? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: I don't really think that you can make something well working without sort of store.For instance the example you posted with inputs, require some initial data into vue instance for specific v-model - so you have to import store data in the Vue instance and then you can attach new property to v-model.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326821/i-am-using-vue-js-and-python-flask-as-my-backend-i-want-to-have-some-local-vari/42326978#42326978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your question that you feel like you are doing something wrong by using the data property of your Vue and not a component, or by adding Vue directives to HTML that exists inside the element of your Vue.

*There's nothing wrong with this*. The [getting started](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started) page for the Vue documentation does this. It's a convenient way to start integrating Vue with various web frameworks. I don't think anyone thinks this is a bad practice. And if someone does, well, who cares?