# Vuejs helper with route

Tags: vue.js

I have a function that is used all over the app.
I would like to export this function to a module and import where is needed.

function inside component:

```
navigate: debounce(function() {
  this.$router.push({
    path: '/cars',
    query: this.params
  })
}, 200)
```

How can I export this function to a module and use on components ?

Comment: This looks like a method that's part of a class, not a standalone function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue - best way to reuse methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723499/vue-best-way-to-reuse-methods)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the function into a mixin (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

funcs.js:

```
export default
{
  methods:
  {
    navigate()
    {
      debounce(() =>
      {
        this.$router.push({
          path: '/cars',
          query: this.params
        });
      }, 200);
    }
  }
}
```

component.vue:

```
import funcs from './funcs.js'

export default
{
  ...
  mixins: [funcs],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you mention this to be used often across your app, you can add a new method to your Vue router instance.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes 
})


// Create and export a pass-through API so you can use it just like router.push
export const debouncedPush = debounce(router.push, 200);

// Add debouncedPush method on the router
router.debouncedPush = debouncedPush

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

And then, in your component code, you can use it like

```
this.$router.debouncedPush({path: '/cars', query: this.params})
```

Or, you can import just the method like:

```
import { debouncedPush } from './path/to/file'
debouncedPush({path: '/cars'})
```

Comment: is there a way to have debouncedPush and router.push working at same time ?

Comment: Adding `debouncedPush` does not affect `router.push` in any way. You can use both independently. (I'm assuming the `debounced` implementation you are using creates a new wrapper function and returns it  (without messing with the underlying function))