# Passing data between child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am struggling for this to work. I need to access the `selected` value in the ChooseLangComponent from the FormComponent. Is there any direct way to do this or we have to pass it from the parent component (act like middle man)? I already tried with `$emit` on ChooseLangComponent and `v-on:..` on FormComponent but didn't work.

ChooseLangComponent:

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="choose-lang">
        <select v-model="selected">
            <option v-for="lang in langs" v-bind:value="lang.value">{{lang.text}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                selected: 'en',
                langs: [
                    { text: 'English', value: 'en' },
                    { text: 'German', value: 'ge' },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

FormComponent:

```
<template lang="html">
    <div class="form-name">
        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" v-model="nameText" v-on:keyup.enter="send_name">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            nameText: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        send_name() {
              // I need the selected language here
        }
    }
}
```

The parent component:

```
<div id="app">
    <choose-lang></choose-lang>
    ...
    <form-comp></form-comp>
</div>

...
Vue.component('choose-lang', require('./components/ChooseLangComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('form-comp', require('./components/FormComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    ...
});
```

Comment: What about something like this - http://jsbin.com/siyipuboki/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay there are 2 easy ways and one more which involves the Vuex, if your app is large scale.

First way is creating the Event Bus - idea is emitting Events in one hub and then catching them where It's needed.

```
const Bus = new Vue({})

Vue.component('lang', {
       template: '#lang-tmp', 
       data() {
            return {
                selected: 'en',
                langs: [
                    { text: 'English', value: 'en' },
                    { text: 'German', value: 'ge' },
                ]
            }
        },
        created() {
          this.changeLang()
        },
        methods: {
          changeLang() {
            Bus.$emit('langChanged', this.selected)
          }
        }
})

Vue.component('frm', {
  template: '#frm-tmp',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItem: 'en'
    }
  },
  created() {
    Bus.$on('langChanged', (selected) => {
      this.selectedItem = selected
    })
  }
})

const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app'

})
```

http://jsbin.com/siyipuboki/edit?html,js,output

Second way is creating sort of store - plain object that would hold the state of selected item

```
const store = {
  data: {
    selected: null
  }
}

Vue.component('lang', {
       template: '#lang-tmp', 
       data() {
            return {
                selected: 'en',
                langs: [
                    { text: 'English', value: 'en' },
                    { text: 'German', value: 'ge' },
                ]
            }
        },
        created() {
          this.changeLang()
        },
        methods: {
          changeLang() {
            store.data.selected = this.selected
          }
        }
})

Vue.component('frm', {
  template: '#frm-tmp',
  data() {
    return {
      storeSelected: store.data
    }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app'

})
```

http://jsbin.com/qagahabile/edit?html,js,output

Also please check this [VueJS access child component's data from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410332/vuejs-access-child-components-data-from-parent/40411389#40411389)

Comment: Thank you, I will accept it as soon as I test it on my project. I would like to give you +1, but can't because of repu...

Comment: There's is problem with the first method. `Bus is not defined`, refering to the Bus within the langComponent. I'm declaring `const Bus = ...` on app.js, and the components are on seperate file (don't know if that's the problem though)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, jsbin works properly without any errors.

Comment: Could you show how you tried to implement this bus solution in your app ?

Comment: Still, when click the button `Bus is not defined`. DO you think this error is due the the components being on diferent files? And the `const Bus = ...` on `app.ps` (question's parent component, another file)

Comment: Expose bus on the window if building in webpack.

Comment: I think the solution 2 would better fit in your case - you can just create new file, export object, fill it with properties you need and import where it's needed (Check link at the end of answer)

Comment: @BertEvans "Expose bus on the window if building in webpack" . Well done (don't know if it's good practice but it worked), just changed `window.Bus = new Vue({})` in the Belmin anwser. Thank you both