# How can I pass properties to a component which is called by router in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am new to VueJs and I have a problem with two components. I am trying to display a component with vuejs router and I must pass properties to that component and since it's not a child of that component (it's in different directory), how can I pass data to that component?
For example:

This is a Parent component:

```
 <template>
    <div class="container">
       <router-link to="/Form"></router-link>
    </div>
</template> 
<script>
  export default{
  data(){
    return{
      values: {val1: 123, val2: 321}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is a components that needs properties, Form component:

```
 <template>
    <div class="container">
       <form>
         <input type="text" v-model="values.val1"/>
         <input type="number" v-model="values.val2"/>
       </form>
    </div>
</template> 
<script>
  export default{
  props: {
    values: {
      type: Object
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the `router-view`?

Comment: It's in App.vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the values as the `query` object:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/Form', query: values }"></router-link>
```

And have the Form component check for the `$route.query` values instead of using `props`:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <input type="text" v-model="values.val1"/>
      <input type="number" v-model="values.val2"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</template> 
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      values: this.$route.query
    }
  }        
}
</script>
```

Note that these values will be added to the URL as a query string.

---

Otherwise, I'd take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155274/passing-data-between-child-components). Or maybe look into [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/).