# Creating a root computed value from component computed values?

Tags: vue.js

I'm somewhat new to Vue and I'm trying to figure out how to access computed values from components' computed values.
Please check out this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/85ma3rct/

```html
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <table>   
      <floor></floor> 
      <floor></floor>
      <floor></floor>
    </table>  
    Largest area: {{ largest_area}}
  </div>
```

```js
Vue.component('floor', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    }
  },
  computed: {
    area: function () {
      return this.width * this.height;
    }
  },  
  template: '<tr><td><input type="number" v-model="width"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="number" v-model="height"></td>' +
            '<td>{{ area }}</td>' +
            '</tr>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    largest_area: function () {
      // How to get this from component computed values...
      return 0
    }
  }, 
})
```

How could I get the largest_area computed value by the computed value from within a number of components?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS access child component's data from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410332/vuejs-access-child-components-data-from-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is watching for area value changes in child component and emit value to parent

```
  watch: {
    area: {
      handler() {
         this.$emit('input', this.area)
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
```

then in parent

```
<table>

  <floor @input="changeVal($event, 0)"></floor> 
  <floor @input="changeVal($event, 1)"></floor>
  <floor @input="changeVal($event, 2)"></floor>

  </table>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    areas: [0, 0, 0]
  },
  computed: {
    largest_area: function () {
        return Math.max(...this.areas)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeVal(val, index) {
       this.$set(this.areas, index, val)
    }
  }
})
```

Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/kuo9crjm/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your `<floor>` components into [custom elements that can use `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components). Each `<floor>` can then emit the computed *area* to its parent which can collect and compute the maximum.

For example

```js
Vue.component('floor', {
  template: `<tr>
  <td><input type="number" v-model="width" @input="update"></td>
  <td><input type="number" v-model="height" @input="update"></td>
  <td>{{ area }}</td>
  </tr>`,
  data: () => ({ width: 20, height: 20 }),
  computed: {
    area() { return this.width * this.height }
  },
  methods: {
    update() { this.$emit('input', this.area) }
  },
  created() { this.update() } // emit the initial value
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { areas: [0, 0, 0] },
  computed: {
    largest_area () { return Math.max(...this.areas) }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <floor v-for="(_, n) in areas" v-model="areas[n]" :key="n"></floor>
  </table>
  Largest area: {{ largest_area }}
</div>
```

Typically, to support `v-model`, your component would have a `value` *prop*. However, since your components initialise their own data, I have omitted that. The only real requirement is that your component emit an *input* event.

Comment: @EvilArthas I don't know what you mean. Everything in this answer is reactive

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$refs` for this Refer - [Refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)

Add a `ref` to your component wherever you import it and use it -

```
<MyComponent ref="child" />
```

Then you can access all it's property from your consuming `component`.

In your consuming component you can access it in `$refs` property like below

```
this.$refs.child.{child-property}
```

Add `ref` to `floor`

```
<table>   
  <floor ref="floor"></floor> 
</table>
```

And then refer it

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    largest_area: function () {
        console.log(this.$refs.floor.area())
        return 0
    }
  }, 
})
```

Comment: This violates [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

Comment: @Phil, `refs` are not reactive anymore which stops `child` from mutating `parent` state accidentally. I am not sure if I missed a point here but this is the recommended way from official docs as per OP requirement - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

Comment: Calling methods is very different to reaching into refs and accessing their data and computed properties. That is not recommended